# Creating a large random number in Racket

Tags: random, racket

I'm trying to generate a very large random number in Racket, something between 0 and 1e20.

`(random)` has the limitation set in the range of 1 and 4294967087.

I've created a hack-y function that tries to generate a random number, but only does so based on order-of-magnitude, not the actual number. Here's that function:

```
define (l-random [min 0] [max 10])
  (define length (random (number-length min) (number-length max)))
  (define string "")
  (for ([i length])
    (set! string (format "~a~a" string (random 0 10))))
  (string->number string))
```

And here's how I calculate order of magnitude:

```
(define (number-length number)
  (cond [(= 0 number) 1]
        [else (+ 1 (exact-floor (log (abs number) 10)))]))
```

Do you have any suggestions or solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Random Number Generation module](https://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/williams/science.plt/4/2/planet-docs/science/random-numbers.html) from the Science Collection has exactly what you are looking for. Here is an example on the DrRacket repl (up to 1e20 per your specification):

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.3 [3m].
Language: racket; memory limit: 256 MB.

> (require (planet williams/science/random-source))

> (random-integer (expt 10 20))
79219429305569404064
```

Which runs in under one second!